# What are the rules for choosing from overloaded template functions?

Tags: c++, templates

Given the code below, why is the `foo(T*)` function selected ?

If I remove it (the `foo(T*)`) the code still compiles and works correctly, but G++ v4.4.0 (and probably other compilers as well) will generate two `foo()` functions: one for char[4] and one for char[7].

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template< typename T >
void foo( const T& )
{
    cout << "foo(const T&)" << endl;
}

template< typename T >
void foo( T* )
{
    cout << "foo(T*)" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    foo( "bar" );
    foo( "foobar" );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Funny, MSVC9 names the function "foo<char[4]>" in the debug symbols, but - apparently as it recognizes the implementation is identical - uses  the same implementation for both calls. - Interesting question, anyway.

Comment: AFAIK VC folds template instances that result in identical code.

Comment: GCC (4.2.4) makes both foo<char[4]> and foo<char[7]> instantiations in anything up until -O3, where it just elides them entirely for these implementations and makes it inline.

Comment: Nick: I explicitely prohibited VC to inline them

Comment: @peterchen: Obviously VC still folds identical instances.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Formally, when comparing conversion sequences, lvalue transformations are ignored. Conversions are grouped into several categories, like *qualification adjustment* (`T*` -> `T const*`), *lvalue transformation* (`int[N]` -> `int*`, `void()` -> `void(*)()`), and others.

The only difference between your two candidates is an lvalue transformation. String literals are arrays that convert to pointers. The first candidate accepts the array by reference, and thus won't need an lvalue transformation. The second candidate requires an lvalue transformation.

So, if there are two candidates that both function template specializations are equally viable by looking only at the conversions, then the rule is that the more specialized one is chosen by doing partial ordering of the two.

Let's compare the two by looking at their signature of their function parameter list

```
void(T const&);
void(T*);
```

If we choose some unique type `Q` for the first parameter list and try to match against the second parameter list, we are matching `Q` against `T*`. This will fail, since `Q` is not a pointer. Thus, the second is at least as specialized as the first.

If we do the other way around, we match `Q*` against `T const&`. The reference is dropped and toplevel qualifiers are ignored, and the remaining `T` becomes `Q*`. This is an exact match for the purpose of partial ordering, and thus deduction of the transformed parameter list of the second against the first candidate succeeds. Since the other direction (against the second) didn't succeed, the second candidate is *more* specialized than the first - and in consequence, overload resolution will prefer the second, if there would otherwise be an ambiguity.

At `13.3.3.2/3`:

> Standard conversion sequence S1 is a better conversion sequence than standard conversion sequence S2 if [...]
>
> - S1 is a proper subsequence of S2 (comparing the conversion sequences in the canonical form
>     defined by 13.3.3.1.1, excluding any Lvalue Transformation; the identity conversion sequence is considered to be a subsequence of any non-identity conversion sequence) or, if not that [...]

Then `13.3.3/1`

> - let ICSi(F) denote the implicit conversion sequence that converts the i-th argument in the list to the type of the i-th parameter of viable function F. 13.3.3.1 defines the implicit conversion sequences and 13.3.3.2 defines what it means for one implicit conversion sequence to be a better conversion sequence or worse conversion sequence than another.
>
> Given these definitions, a viable function F1 is defined to be a better function than another viable function F2 if for all arguments i, ICSi(F1) is not a worse conversion sequence than ICSi(F2), and then [...]
>
> - F1 and F2 are function template specializations, and the function template for F1 is more specialized than the template for F2 according to the partial ordering rules described in 14.5.5.2, or, if not that, [...]

Finally, here is the table of implicit conversions that may participate in an standard conversion sequence at `13.3.3.1.1/3`.

[Conversion sequences http://img259.imageshack.us/img259/851/convs.png](http://img259.imageshack.us/img259/851/convs.png)

Comment: This is NOT a case of non-template preference, because there is no non-template function to be chosen by the compiler.  The fact is that const char [] is a much closer match to T* than T& (because const char [] and const char * are equivalent).

Comment: sorry i overlooked the template<...> clause before the second one. fixed :)

Comment: Your assertion that the match to `T*` is closer is wrong, though :)

Comment: @litb: If my assertion was wrong, the compiler wouldn't very well agree with me.  const T[N] > const T* > const T&, in this case.  Of course, he doesn't supply a const T[N] overload, so const T* wins (well, in the OP case, T*, which is weaker yet, but still preferable to the compiler than const T&).

Comment: @litb: I think we just disagree on the definition of "closer"...I merely mean "closer" to be "more preferable" in the eyes of the standard (and thus, compiler).

Comment: I was going to add a different comment, but I realise that my previous comment wsa OK! :(  Anyway, just to re-state it, if you add an overlad with reerence to array:   "template <typename T, int I> void foo (T (&)[I])" then this results in an ambiguous call error, since partial ordering cannot distinguish between the specializations.

Comment: @Richard, sure your previous comment was fine :) (maybe i'm gonna enhance my answer, but not now i'm waaay too tired right now). :)

Answer (score 2):

The full answer is quite technical.

First, string literals have `char const[N]` type.

Then there is an implicit conversion from `char const[N]` to `char const*`.

So both your template function match, one using reference binding, one using the implicit conversion.  When they are alone, both your template functions are able to handle the calls, but when they are both present, we have to explain why the second foo (instantiated with T=char const[N]) is a better match than the first (instantiated with T=char).  If you look at the overloading rules (as given by litb), the choice between

```
void foo(char const (&x)[4));
```

and

```
void foo(char const* x);
```

is ambigous (the rules are quite complicated but you can check by writing non template functions with such signatures and see that the compiler complains).  In that case, the choice is made to the second one because that one is more specialized (again the rules for this partial ordering are complicated, but in this case it is because you can pass a `char const[N]` to a `char const*` but not a `char const*` to a `char const[N]` in the same way as `void bar(char const*)` is more specialized than `void bar(char*)` because you can pass a `char*` to a `char const*` but not vise-versa).

Answer (score 0):

Based on overload resolution rules (Appendix B of [C++ Templates: The Complete Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201734842) has a good overview), string literals (const char []) are closer to T* than T&, because the compiler makes no distinction between char[] and char*, so T* is the closest match (const T* would be an exact match).

In fact, if you could add:

```
template<typename T>
void foo(const T[] a)
```

(which you can't), your compiler would tell you that this function is a redefinition of:

```
template<typename T>
void foo(const T* a)
```

Comment: `T*` is by no means a closer match. Try `void f(char const(&)[1]); void f(char const*); int main() { f(""); }`: This call, which resembles the situation of above using non-templates, is ambiguous.

Comment: @litb: T* is a much closer match than T& in this case.  Yes, if you include a specific SIZE (&[N]), then that makes it ambiguous, but T* matches an arbitrary array much more closely than T& does.

Comment: @Nick, while void foo(T x[]) is a synonym of void foo(T* x), it doesn't mean that you can't instantiate void foo(T&) with T being an array type.  The equivalent is void foo(ArrayBaseType (&)[ArraySize])

Comment: @AProgrammer: Right, I didn't mean to suggest that you can't do that (in fact, it's clear that the compiler will, given no other options), but merely that it is less preferred.

Comment: @Nick, Please quote the appropriate Standard sections, instead of making more and more claims. Your analysis seems to be slightly off to me, frankly speaking.

Comment: @litb: 4.2(2) specifies that string literal conversion (used in this case because we have no explicit overload of a given array size) is considered array-to-pointer followed by qualification-conversion (for the purpose of ranking in overload resolution). Both T* and T qualify as "Exact Match" rank for the purposes of each conversion in the sequence, but T& has a "Conversion" rank for reference binding under 13.3.3.1.4, meaning that T* is a better match under 13.3.3.1.1.3, since it has "Exact Match" for reference binding. At least, that's how I read it.

Comment: @Nick, "123" binding to a `T const&` when `T` is a template parameter, then the conversion sequence is the identity conversion (thus, it contains no conversion): Because the `T const&` binds directly to the argument `"123"` (13.3.3.1.4/1) (with `T` becoming `char[4]`). Even if we was to accept `T&`, then `T` will become `char const[4]`, and this will be an exact match too: the resulting function parameter has type `char const(&)[4]`. The qualification conversion you mentioned has not to do with this, but with `char *c = "123";`. But in our examples, there nowhere appears a type `char*`.

Comment: Note that there is a "reference compatible with added qualification". This happens for example with `void f(int const&); int a; int main() { f(a) }`. But this will still be an exact match (identity conversion). Nevertheless, it can influence the rank of the conversion sequence, as shown by  `void f(int const&); void f(int&); int a; int main() { f(a); }` it will call the second one, because it is less const qualified. But it won't do any conversion. When doing argument deduction against `T*`, (argument is still `"123"` with type `char const[4]`), an lvalue transformation ...

Comment: (array to pointer conversion) happens by the deduction process, to get type `char const*` (then `A = char const*` and `P = T*` when entering `14.8.2.4`). The compiler will then deduce `char const` for T, and thus will build a function parameter of type `char const*`. Now, `"123"` needs a lvalue transformation for the call to succeed (array to pointer), but no qualification conversion or whatsoever. So, actually, the `T*` one has one conversion more. This array->pointer conversion, however, is ignored when comparing two conversion sequences. And this, the call would be ambiguous ...

Comment: Now, the compiler sees that both candidates are functions that were instantiated from templates, and will lookup their templates, determining a partial ordering. Then, the candidate corresponding to the more specialized template (if there exist an order between them) will be chosen by overload resolution. And that is in our case the `T*` version. Hope my analysis in the comments clear the matter up.

Answer (score -1):

Cause " " is a char*, which fits perfectly to foo(T*) function. When you remove this, the compiler will try to make it work with foo(T&), which requires you to pass reference to char array that contains the string.

Compiler can't generate one function that would receive reference to char, as you are passing whole array, so it has to dereference it.

Comment: Wrong too. Please don't guess. `""` is a `char const[1]`. You also cannot `pass reference`. Expressions always have non-reference type.

Comment: I never said it's not (actually, it's " ", co it's const[2]), what I meant is that chosing T* function is preferred, if it's exists. As for the `passing ref` statement, I was trying to say, that less preferred option is T&, which is basically, a reference to T (in this case, reference to char[N]), although my response did not sound quite correct, your right with that one. Correct me if I'm wrong (and after you do, I'll just remove my post, as it's not useful compared to yours, which is much more complete).