# GCC, Clang, and IBM disagree on how to perform template-parameter-dependent name lookup. Which one is right?

Tags: c++, templates, argument-dependent-lookup

Consider this example I found on IBM's website:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void f(double) { cout << "Function f(double)" << endl; }

template<class T> void g(T a) {
  f(123);
  h(a);
}

void f(int) { cout << "Function f(int)" << endl; }
void h(double) { cout << "Function h(double)" << endl; }

void i() {
  extern void h(int);
  g<int>(234);
}

void h(int) { cout << "Function h(int)" << endl; }

int main(void) {
    i();
}
```

What will it print?

- The IBM documentation I adapted this example from, available [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v101v121/advanced/print.jsp?printType=singleTopicPrint&linkId=t1_2_16_6), says it will print:

  ```
  Function f(double)
  Function h(double)
  ```

  The rationale for this is that template-parameter-dependent name lookup is performed right before the instantiation of `i()`, so it finds `h(double)` but not `h(int)`.
- When I compile it using GCC 4.4.1, it prints:

  ```
  Function f(double)
  Function h(int)
  ```

  GCC seems to be looking up the template-parameter-dependent names in the template after everything else has been compiled, so it finds both `h(double)` and `h(int)`, and prefers the latter.
- When I compile it using Clang 2.8, it fails to compile. The compiler error is:

  ```
  ibm_example.cc:8:3: error: use of undeclared identifier 'h'
    h(a);
    ^
  ibm_example.cc:16:3: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'g<int>' requested here
    g<int>(234);
    ^
  1 error generated.
  ```

  Clang seems to be looking up the template-parameter-dependent names in the template at the point where the template is declared, so it finds neither `h(double)` nor `h(int)`.

Which one is right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the rules for choosing from overloaded template functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177739/what-are-the-rules-for-choosing-from-overloaded-template-functions)

Comment: No change for GCC 4.5.1 FWIW.

Comment: @Foo : This is definitely _not_ a duplicate of that question -- that one is about overload resolution, this one is about scope and what symbols are visible at the point of definition.

Comment: This is an excellent question!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

They are all correct. No really, read on...

```
template<class T> void g(T a) {
  f(123);
  h(a);
}
```

Here, `f` is a non-dependent name but `h` is a dependent name according to 14.6.2/1. `f` is looked up

> Non-dependent names used in a template definition are found using the usual name lookup and bound at
>   the point they are used.

`f` is looked up immediately and bound to `void f(double)`, the only `f` visible at that point.

According to 14.6.4.1 the point of instantiation of `void g<int>(int)` is immediately after the definition of `void i()`, where it is used.

> [..]Otherwise, the point of instantiation for such a specialization
>   immediately follows the namespace scope declaration or definition that refers to the specialization.

This means that sources for resolving the dependent name are declarations visible at the definition of `template<class T> void g(T a)` and "declarations from namespaces associated with the types of the function arguments both from the instantiation context (14.6.4.1) and from the definition context" (14.6.4).

However, because `int` is a fundemantal type, the set of associated namespaces is empty (3.4.2) (no, not even the global namespace is included) and according to 14.6.4.2 it is only lookup using the associated namespaces that can use the template instantiation context, normal unqualified name lookup can only use what is visible at the template definition context. This confirms what was said in 14.6.4.

Now, the bonus point. 14.6.4.2 goes on to say:

> If the call would be ill-formed or would find a better match had the lookup within the associated namespaces considered all the function declarations with external linkage introduced in those namespaces in all translation units, not just considering those declarations found in the template definition and template instantiation contexts, then the program has undefined behavior.

The call *is* ill formed because lookup fails (the part about associated namespaces doesn't apply here), so the behavior is explicitly *undefined* so anything could happen. Hence none of the behaviours seen shows a non-conformance with the standard although, to me, Clang's diagnostic seem most in keeping with the standard.

(All references ISO/IEC 14882:2011.)

Comment: One can interpret the part about undefined behavior with a different binding, which appears to make more sense to me: "If {{the call would be ill-formed} or {would find a better match} had the lookup within associated namespaces considered all the function declarations with external linkage introduced in those namespaces in all translation units}, ... then the program has undefined behavior".

Comment: Or worded differently (later part of the paragraph "If {{the call would be ill-formed} or {would find a better match} had the lookup within associated namespaces not just considered those declarations found in the template definition and template instantiation contexts}, then the program has undefined behavior.".

Comment: This binding makes more sense to me because the compiler (as opposed to the linker) cannot look at multiple translation units, hence the Standard doesn't require a diagnostic for those cases where when the implementation would do so, the call would be ambiguous/ill-formed or find a better match.

Comment: In effect, I think this rule can be considered an extension of the rules found in the ODR/other parts of the spec, which rules undefined if any of the multiple instantiations have different behavior. Under this word binding, we will rule undefined if the template, if instantiated using an instantiation context consisting of the union of all individual instantiation contexts, would have function call behavior that is different from one/more of the individual instantiations.

Comment: In the end of course, I can only evaluate what interpretation makes more sense to me. I wasn't there when these rules were set up. It would be better if the Standard had a bullet list here for clarity. As it is now, one cannot rely on whether it means "If it is illformed ..., ... behavior is undefined." or whether it means "If it is illformed ... had the lookup within the associated namespaces ..., behavior is undefined.". FWIW, GCC4.7 trunk now complies with the rules and behaves like Clang.

Comment: My brain hurts understanding this part of your question : `it is only lookup using the associated namespaces that can use the template instantiation context, normal unqualified name lookup can only use what is visible at the template definition context`.

Comment: So I tried to look it up in C++ standard you pointed and it's written there: 14.6.4.2 `For the part of the lookup using unqualified name lookup (3.4.1), only **function declarations with external
linkage from the template definition context are found**`  . I couldn't figure out what last sentence tried to say "external linkage from template definition" ?

Comment: Re. the final point about explicit UB: without this clause then the program would be ill-formed (since the call is ill-formed); so it seems to me that this is just the same thing as what the standard describes in other places as "ill-formed, no diagnostic required", i.e. the executable has complete UB but the compiler doesn't have to say anything.