# Wrong overloaded template function is called

Tags: c++, templates, overloading

I have the following code with overloaded template functions

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
const T& max(const T& a1, const T& a2)
{
    cout << "general template" << endl;
    return (a1 < a2) ? a2 : a1;
}

template <class T>
const T* max(const T* a1, const T* a2)
{
    cout << "max for pointers" << endl;
    return (a1 < a2) ? a2 : a1;
}

template <class T>
const T& max(const T& a1, const T& a2, const T& a3)
{
    cout << "general template with three parameters" << endl;
    return ::max(::max(a1, a2), ::max(a1, a2));
}

int main()
{
    int* a = new int(5);
    int* b = new int(56);
    int* c = new int(2);
    int*const  &g = ::max(a, b, c);
    cout << *g << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I was expecting it to fail, because the max template with three parameters would return reference to a temporary variable (returned by template for pointers). But it works and calls general template function.

The question is why doesn't called template for pointers?

Thanks.

Comment: I would avoid `using namespace std;`, even more when you declare function with conflicting name (`std::max` exists).

Comment: Thanks for advice. I just was testing template functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you comment out the definition of 2-argument `max` for references, you would see that the code does not compile. The error that MSVC++2013 gives at line 22 is:

```
error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'const int *' to 'int *const &'
```

That seems to be the reason why `max` for references is always selected: template substitution fails for `max` for pointers.
If you change the code to the following, then template for pointers is called:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
T max(const T& a1, const T& a2)
{
    cout << "general template" << endl;
    return (a1 < a2) ? a2 : a1;
}

template <class T>
T* max(T* a1, T* a2)
{
    cout << "template for pointers" << endl;
    return (a1 < a2) ? a2 : a1;
}

template <class T>
T max(const T& a1, const T& a2, const T& a3)
{
    cout << "general template with three parameters" << endl;
    return ::max(::max(a1, a2), a3);
}

int main()
{
    int* a = new int(5);
    int* b = new int(56);
    int* c = new int(2);
    int* g = ::max(a, b, c);
    cout << *g << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

If you comment out the definition of the template for pointers, then the template for references is called. The preference of template for pointers over template for references seems to happen because the type is already a pointer.

Here is some explanation on the order of template matching: [What are the rules for choosing from overloaded template functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177739/what-are-the-rules-for-choosing-from-overloaded-template-functions)

EDIT: the OP's code can be altered in another way, so that MSVC++2013 prefers reference-based template to pointer-based:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
T max(const T& a1, const T& a2)
{
    cout << "general template" << endl;
    return (a1 < a2) ? a2 : a1;
}

template <class T>
const T* max(const T* a1, const T* a2)
{
    cout << "template for pointers" << endl;
    return (a1 < a2) ? a2 : a1;
}

template <class T>
T max(const T& a1, const T& a2, const T& a3)
{
    cout << "general template with three parameters" << endl;
    return const_cast<const T>(::max(::max(a1, a2), a3));
}

int main()
{
    int* a = new int(5);
    int* b = new int(56);
    int* c = new int(2);
    int* g = ::max(a, b, c);
    cout << *g << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This happens because in this version pointer-based template definition has additional qualifiers for its parameter types: they are not just `T*`, but rather `const T*`.

Comment: The top level const is not part of the match, I think it'd be clearer to take it out

Comment: @MattMcNabb, what do you mean by "top level const"?

Comment: @MattMcNabb, I've removed unnecessary const.

Comment: @Jarod42, we shouldn't solve all problems at once in this single question. From the example it's clear that home-grown max is called because `std::max` doesn't print anything. `std::max` is in <algorithm> header file, this example doesn't include that header.

Comment: @SergeRogatch: Oups, I wanted to add the remark to question... Fixed.

Comment: Template argument deduction *does not* fail for the pointer version in OP's code; this kind of deduction is explicitly allowed by the standard. The error that is issued if you comment out the 2-arg `max` for references is not caused by deduction failure, but rather by something close to what the OP was expecting - reference binding to the result of 3-arg `max`. The reason for the reference version being called in OP's code is that, after template argument deduction succeeds for both overloads, the reference one is chosen by overload resolution because of better conversions.

Comment: The conversions for the reference overload specialization are identity conversions (the reference binds directly), while the conversions for the pointer version are qualification conversions (`int*` to `const int*`). In your code, after you removed the `const`, the two specializations resulting from the two overloads are equally good based on conversions, so overload resolution resorts to partial ordering of function templates, which yields the pointer one as more specialized.

Comment: Isn't this version now forcing copies to be made? This could be an issue when not comparing pointers.

Comment: @bogdan, have you tried commenting out the 2-argument `max` taking reference in OP's code? MSVC++ then gives the following error: `error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'const int *' to 'int *const &'`

Comment: @SergeRogatch Exactly. That error is not caused by a deduction failure, as I explained in my first comment. Do something else: in the original code, comment out the reference version and change the implementation of the 3-arg `max` to `return const_cast<int*>(::max(::max(a1, a2), ::max(a1, a2)));`. This will compile with no errors (just warnings, for the problem that OP expected). This shows that the problem is not with deduction for the 2-arg `max`. (Note that the code is semantically incorrect - it's just the quickest way to silence the error you mentioned, just to show where it comes from.)

Comment: @bogdan, the cause-effect relation is the opposite: substitution of pointer-based template fails because of that error. See https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/SFINAE

Comment: My concern about copies is valid: http://ideone.com/Pq8Koq Now this max would be a bad fit for everything that is not a pointer.

Comment: @DanielJour, ok, copies of the objects are created upon returning from the functions. But the question is "why is the template for pointers not called" in the OP's code. It is wrong to discuss "the best implementation of max()" here.

Comment: @SergeRogatch No, that's not correct. Template argument deduction and substitution, and subsequent overload resolution, are done in order to find a suitable function to call *for the given arguments* in this case. That's all; the subsequent initialization done by the return statement is not part of either of the above. After the best viable function is chosen, if something's wrong with that initialization, it's a hard error, not a silent SFINAE-type deduction failure.

Comment: @SergeRogatch To further prove this, do another experiment: take the original code, with both overloads, and change the implementation of the 3-arg `max` to the following: `::max(::max(a1, a2), ::max(a1, a2)); return a1;`. Now we've taken the conversion from the return value out of the equation. If that conversion were indeed the reason for a deduction failure and for the pointer overload not being chosen, now it's gone, right? Still, the code prints `general template` in this case as well, proving that the reference overload is chosen for different reasons, as I explained above.

Comment: @bogdan, in your example the template function taking pointers is still not a viable substitution, and that is not because of return type, but because the arguments which `max` takes.

Comment: @SergeRogatch *It is* a viable function. Comment out the reference overload and now the code prints `max for pointers`.

Comment: @bogdan, it seems I see what you mean, but right now I can't test it thoroughly. Perhaps you should provide a separate answer (or even a question) explaining your view.

Comment: @SergeRogatch True, I just thought this should be noted, as it's a possible change in semantics. IMHO it's best to provide a different name for a function that is doing more (dereferencing) as what the name `max` suggests.

Comment: @SergeRogatch The goal, in my opinion, is to have a correct and complete accepted answer - that was the reason for my comments. I think having four competing answers to this question isn't going to help anyone who will look at it in the future. In short, I suggest you clarify things and (if necessary) update the answer when you have the time.

Comment: @bogdan, actually I have already answered what I could. It is a bad idea to force me to say beyond my understanding. The alternatives you mention, if described all with code examples, would make the answer much bigger. Actually I don't know how to make a good answer out of them. If you know - please, do that. If there is something that is wrong in my answer and code example - I could fix it. But I see that you talk about extensions and alternative experiments with code changes. That seems reasonable to go to a separate answer. It is wrong to try one size to fit all.

Comment: @SergeRogatch I'm sorry if my last comment wasn't clear. It was never my intention to force you to say anything beyond your understanding, or to have you make an answer out of my examples. My examples have only one purpose: to prove to you that you're making some false assertions in your answer. My first two comments explained what the problems are. You then contradicted that, and I answered with examples to prove that my initial comments are correct. Those examples have no place otherwise in a correct answer to the question.

Answer (score 2):

It's not working. It seems to be working, because you're only using the first two parameters or your three parameter max function.

```
template <class T>
const T& max(const T& a1, const T& a2, const T& a3)
{
    cout << "general template with three parameters" << endl;
    return ::max(
         ::max(a1, a2),
         ::max(a1, a2)); // HERE
}
```

Correcting that shows what is going on: You're comparing pointer addresses.

See [here in action](http://ideone.com/etFt1Q).

Your pointer overload isn't called because the reference version is a better fit: `a1` etc ARE const references (to pointers, but well). So the reference version is a perfect match on respect to overload resolution.

I guess to achieve what you want you'd need some SFINAE magic here.

---

One thing I'd like to add: since comparing pointers is a frequent operation in C++, IMHO it would be very misleading to have some `max` dereference the pointers before comparing.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `max(a, b, c)`,`T` in `max(const T& a1, const T& a2, const T& a3)` becomes an aliases of `int *`,so  in max(const T& a1, const T& a2, const T& a3)
`max(a,b)` will match `max(const T& a1, const T& a2)`

---

```
typedef int * T;
const T x;
const int * y;  //they are different
```

Comment: No, the code is written so that template substitution simply fails for `max` for pointers. You can see that if you comment out the definition of `max` for references: there would be a compile error. If the compile error is fixed, then `max` for pointers is always selected, because the type in 3-argument `max` is a pointer.